# How can I deal with people asking to switch seats with me on a plane?

Tags: air-travel, seating, etiquette

I'm sixteen years old, and I have mild claustrophobia so I always travel in the aisle seat. However, I'm constantly asked (not politely) by others to change seats with them. Since I usually travel alone, this becomes quite problematic for me. I've had instances where a grown man asked me (a child) to sit in his toilet-adjacent seat at the back of the plane. Societal norms prohibit me from punching such people in the face, and in many cases I feel obliged to give people my seat, despite the discomfort I will face as a result of it.

**How can I diplomatically and politely (and firmly) assert that I am not interested in changing seats?** Do note that I am very shy and submissive in public.

Comment: Call the flight attendant and ask her to help the passenger that is bothering you.

Comment: I personally feel very rude by involving the flight attendant @JonathanReez. Especially in cases where they aren't really bothering me, they're just being impolite in asking me to change with them.

Comment: I would point out that in many places of the world, a sixteen year old isn't a child. He (or she) _may_ be a minor, but not a child.

Comment: If you feel pressed in changing with them to a seat which is not to  your liking, they are bothering you. And if a simple NO is not enough to get them to move on, you are in your rights to call for a flight attendant.

Comment: Physical abuse is most definitely *not* the answer. `No`, on the other hand, is.

Comment: @JoErNanO Physical abuse is a tantalising option when a grown man incessantly tells you that his toilet-adjacent seat is `"very good I assure, come come I switch"` and proceeds to pick up your backpack. In that particular case I did call the flight attendant, and deliver unto this man some choice words. I live in India, a land of many wonders. Unfortunately, basic courtesy is not common.

Comment: it can be tough to do, but just don't worry about it. say "no", and put some headphones on or something. no one has a right to your seat, and you don't have to give it up if you don't want to. that's all there is to it. if someone has a problem with that, it's not *your* problem. you paid for your seat.

Comment: I guess the fact that you're in India changes the cultural context a bit, in Europe nobody would dare to ask someone to switch to a reserved seat near the toilet (noisy) just because they're younger and especially insist on it and even touch your stuff.
I would burst out in laughter at such a proposal, that man had no self-respect.

Comment: @Formagella And he was travelling with his wife and child! (seated in a different part of the plane, but they saw the exchange).

Comment: If a couple repetitions of a polite no does not work tell them to get lost in English or Hindi. I always play-act great offence when some ne'er-do-well touches my property for their own benefit (squeegee kids come to mind)-- in no way should you tolerate that any more than you would tolerate them touching your body. *Act* angry, don't get angry, and (at least in my culture) swearing means the other person wins (especially in a family environment), but you can certainly raise your voice in righteous indignation.

Comment: Can you maybe explain why you are "constantly asked"? I understand that it could happen once in 100 trips, but fail to see a reason that this happens constantly to anyone.

Comment: I agree with Quora's question.  I doubt you are **constantly asked**.

Comment: You bought a seat. Treat it like anything you've purchased that someone else asked for. "Can I have that iPhone you paid for?". I know it's hard to say no to people that ask...but realize that's why people ask...they know it's hard for some people to say no. Realize that they are perfectly expecting some to say 'no' and will just go on to the next person.

Comment: "I've had it with these motherfu*king snakes on this..." or you could just pull out your sunglasses, and say "deal with it" after you slowly put it on..

Comment: @JoeBlow: Do you have a lot of experience in India flights? I can assure you that people will usually have a bigger mouth and are more "brave" against minors here in Germany, too. It's an old mammal thing: Whom you are afraid of, you molest not. People who typically shy away from everything and have no backbone suddenly become poor a**holes when they think they are superior. There's the "bedeutungsschwanger" ("pregnant with meaning") in German to describe their sudden urge to impose alpha males/females or importance.

Comment: @QuoraFeans It has happened to me on at least five occasions in the last four years. I travel quite often but you can imagine, it's quite a lot.

Comment: @JoeBlow Oh me neither, two incidents happened on international flights and one was on a trans-UK flight. (UK-Scotland flight for those who insist).

Comment: You said they're rude to you in the process.  This ceases any need to be "submissive" or particularly respectful while declining.  Tell them "no" very clearly (yet unabusively), and if they won't leave you alone, tell staff that you're being harassed by the other passenger and have them deal with them.

Comment: Vedant Chandra  I wouldn't feel bad about calling an attendant - you're just helping out the fellow who needs a new seat. You'd love to help, but you have good and sufficient reason to need the seat you have. (And once they start touching your stuff, then it really is time to bring in the authorities.)

Comment: I'd say, "Oh, sorry, I actually swapped my seat with that guy." (Point finger randomly, don't be specific/clear.) This should do it.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

> "Sir/Ma'am, no thank you." *or* "Sir/Ma'am, I am not interested."

Followed by (if needed)

> "Sir/Ma'am, I am sorry, but I specifically requested and was given this seat. I am not willing to change to another seat for any reason. Perhaps someone else might wish to help you."

Comment: Seeing such a simple answer, I suppose my question was a little silly. I just needed validation that saying this isn't rude I suppose :) Thank you!

Comment: Flying is (for some) an uncomfortable experience. For many others, it is borderline traumatic. NEVER believe that anything you personally experience, or feel, while flying (especially commercially) is silly. It is not rude to turn down a request. In fact, if the requester was doing anything _but_ politely requesting, _they_ were the rude ones.

Comment: I have always learned that any question simple can be answered by Yes, No or Maybe. And if you say No the other has to respect it. They may not like it but they could have booked a special seat themselves, so I agree. Say NO.

Comment: Even if it is perceived as rude, do you care? After all, your safety and comfort come first than that of pushy strangers on a plane.

Comment: I find a big enthusiastic smile with "no thanks!" works well, especially when someone wasn't really asking properly or being polite. "Please accept this flower from..." no thanks, but thanksomuchhaveagreatdayanyway! It doesn't make you feel bad and it tends to bewilder people who were being rude. It also provides a wonderful contrast if they get pushy, when you drop the smile and look directly at them with a flat "no...thank...you..." - it shows you are awful nice and polite, and if they push it that is going to wear off in a hurry and you aren't a push over, so kick rocks. Works 99%!

Comment: @Willeke's comment is spot-on. "No" is always an acceptable response to requests, and anyone who treats someone (especially a minor) who says "no" as if they were being rude is a very rude person themselves.

Comment: @VedantChandra this is also true for much of all other aspect of your live. This isn't like your parents asking you to move "or else" and "don't talk back to me".

Comment: This is a very good answer.  The core of this is do not present your reasons: presenting reasons gives someone something to argue with.

Comment: CG, since you have the top answer.  An overwhelming fact here is that Vedant has mentioned, he prefers not to call for a crew member.  This is a **huge mistake**.  i think the number one thing you tell younger people, who must fly alone, is **do not hesitate to call for a crew member, reflexively, for any reason whatsoever, if anyone else tries to get involved with you for any reason**.  It's absolutely critical.  And even though you're 16, Vedant, not a little kid, you should do this FOR SURE.

Comment: @JoeBlow I haven't agreed with a lot of your comments before, but this one makes a lot of sense. The reason I hesitated to go in that direction was this: if he were 6, let's say, the rude pax wouldn't even talk to him, he'd go directly to the attendant responsible for him. Since he's 16, he's at the cusp of being responsible for himself. That pax might still be able to go to the attendant and suggest that the minor be moved. If the attendant resp for him says 'move' then the OP is in a worse position. If he takes resp for himself, that keeps the resp adult (steward, etc) out of it.

Comment: As a minor child flying alone ( in a so called Western country (European/American)) the child is the responsibility of the airline and will have been assigned an airline steward/attendant as a responsible adult, ensuring the child is seated, etc. (as far as I understand it...I've never traveled as a minor unaccompanied) If that steward says "move" then the child has to move. I was trying to suggest that the OP (still a minor) try to avoid being directed to do so by authority. (Since this is India, I don't know if it is the same or not)

Comment: @JoeBlow OK. I will bow to your knowledge, as I have neither experience as an U/M, or sending an U/M on a trip. That was just _why_ I didn't suggest going to the crew. Fear that the crew would side with the rude pax and not the minor.

Comment: @BrianDHall is right, "No thank you" (in a situation where actually they want something from you and so you have nothing to thank them for really) can work very well.

Comment: +1, mostly because you've answered the question without casting needless aspersions on people who want to switch seats.

Answer (score 89):

The other answers are excellent, and correct. I wanted to share a few extra ideas because you specifically said:

> Do note that I am very shy and submissive in public.

I also am a shy person that's, for various reasons, done a lot of travelling on my own. What I always say to myself is:

> You'll never see any of these people *ever* again.

And that gives me (in my mind) permission to be someone else, to tell people no, to argue that I'm due the seat I paid for, or to sing karaoke, or whatever. Particularly if they're not asking nicely. Any embarrassment I feel is going to disappear at the exit of the airport, at the latest. Travelling alone is a great chance to try things you normally wouldn't do -- and, who knows, you may feel comfortable doing them when you're back home as well. Everyone else is right, it's completely your right to refuse, but if that's really against your nature just pretend to be someone else for the flight. Don't go overboard, but you can be someone that's pleasant but firm and fair -- and who doesn't worry about it,

That's one side of it, but from experience somedays you just can't, on those days I use avoidance tactics that you can employ too. Put headphones in when you sit down (there doesn't have anything playing), close your eyes and *relax*. Only the rudest of the rude people will target you to ask to change seats in that situation. And you'll avoid any small talk with the people next to you if you're not feeling up to it.

But, above all, however you do it, do what everyone else said, and just say no.

Comment: I really appreciate this personal advice, thank you :)

Comment: Pretend to be someone else - excellent advice! You have history on your side. We often use "persona" to mean "a role or character _adopted_ by an actor". The word "persona" comes from the Greek word for the mask that players would wear on stage - and each actor had multiple "personas" and would switch back and forth as the role(s) demanded. By all means, acquire an assertive "man on a plane you don't mess with" persona! "You will never see these people again". Stay polite, but firm.

Comment: And if you use a persona often enough you'll one day realise that your shyness has disappeared and you've _become_ that persona. You didn't even notice it happening, but it did. Trust me. :)

Comment: `You'll never see any of these people ever again.`. That is not my case. It happened to me several times

Comment: As a matter of fact, at least in German there's the saying "you always meet twice in your lifetime". Nonetheless if that helps you saying "No" it's okay to think so, but don't do something you might actually regret later on...

Comment: This held true for me until I ran into someone I knew at the airport 10 minutes ago! :D

Comment: Some people you do meet twice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lVY8s0GQzwg

Answer (score 47):

Unless it is a safety related reason, it will be very hard to change your seat without you willing to do so, that includes cabin crew.

So, as mentioned in the other answer by @CGCampbell, just politely say no. You might get frowned upon but who cares! it is your seat and it is totally your right to be stuck with it.

Something worth mentioning here, airlines in general try their best to put people in their preferable seats, but it is almost an impossible job to do, so ground agents try to spare of that headache to cabin crew, who also will try to spare some of that headache to passengers, so it is not abnormal to see cabin crew "hiding" during boarding to avoid the extra headache and embarrassment and let passengers solve things. If that ever happens to you and you felt uncomfortable by requests, just inform cabin crew. If they were available most likely passengers will not bother fellow passengers and will try to ask cabin crew instead. Cabin crew are trained on how to turn down requests with a big smile.

Regarding punching people who ask for your seat in the face, no need to do that. Actually you will be giving them a big favor if you got physical or rude. Crew can then offload you according to the international "unruly passengers" regulations and then take your seat. So just say no and enjoy the ride.

One last thing, as a cabin crew I know of a few ways to make people willingly give up their seats. Don't fall for that. One of these techniques is asking a passenger with a voice that passengers around can hear and then saying something like "Sir, are you interested in switching your seat so that family can stay together", this will be hard to refuse, since refusing publicly will make you look like an evil. Do not fall for that, just refuse with a smarter answer, something like "I would love to, but due to my health reasons I specifically requested this seat".

Comment: +1, good with the 'family sit together' and 'would love to but..' example.

Comment: +1. Thanks for revealing (how to defend against) an insider trick!

Comment: it seems inconceivable a crew member would ask an unaccompanied minor to change seats!!  if one of my children, solo, was asked **by a crew member** to change seats, I would literally take legal action against the airline.  aircrew **lavish attention on** the legal horrors of solo youths flying, so they can never be caught out and sued- it would seem amazing that this could happen.

Comment: @JoeBlow No one was talking about unaccompanied minors here. This is just an example. Take it easy dad :)

Comment: Hi keelYou -- fair enough, -- thanks for pointing this out -- I may have misunderstood!?  He's 16 right, isn't that in the unaccompanied minor age range for many airlines?  (I actually thought "all"?)  Note that you simply **can't book a flight on expedia** as a 16 year old, it's 18 minimum, for this reason.  they tell you to go direct to the airlines if under 18.

Comment: @joe the airline I work for set the age at 15 for emergency exits, and to travel alone you must be 12 or more. So it depends.

Comment: sure; I'm always amazed that relatively often you get 6 or 7 year olds flying alone, even on the longest flights (Aus to europe); conversely it does seem a bit stodgy that expedia makes a blanket 18 year default.  note that the OP is literally "unaccompanied" and a "minor" (16 is a legal minor in most jurisdictions, including India I believe).

Comment: "Unaccompanied minor" in aviation usually means something else I guess, in my country you ate a minor until 21, but when it comes to flying it means something else. I guess its about having to make special arrangements with the airlines if you are under that age.

Comment: @Smalltown2k: How is this a result of *stupidity*? Quite often there simply aren't enough tickets next to each other when the family is buying the ticket.

Comment: @Mehrdad if this was a critical issue for them, then they should have bought when there were enough seats together available, or maybe just get over having to sit split up for a few hours and not try and make it everyone else's problem. Or, which was my point, use the tools available to select seats near to or close to one another.

Comment: @Smalltown2k: You seem pretty inconsiderate...

Comment: @Mehrdad What's inconsiderate is expecting other passengers to make concessions because the persons in question did not use the options available to obviate the issue. I may have used non-diplomatic language, by my point stands.

Answer (score 30):

As a young person, **you should never, ever, swap seats with anyone.**

Here's a thing for you to say:

"I am not allowed to do that. Please bring one of the cabin crew. I've pressed the button to call a cabin crew..."

Whatever the joker says back, just keep repeating, "I better speak to a crew member, here I'll press the button..."

Please note Vedant, you say

## "I personally feel very rude by involving the flight attendant..."

Nonsense!

It is **imperative** that you involve the flight attendants. They are there to help you.

If the person beside you is acting weird, call for a crew member.  If the person beside you is coughing all over you, call for a crew member.  If some fool is talking to you about seating positions, call for a crew member.

This is imperative for younger fliers.

Sure, some adults have the aplomb to handle such situations on their own. But anyone who does not, and any young person must **call for a crew member**. Don't hesitate!  They are there to solve any crazy problems other passengers are causing you.

Comment: +1 as this is a very good general rule, replace by 'police' or 'teacher' in other situations. "Call for help" is a good basic rule.

Comment: +1, good advice overall. I did some reality checks on that (having my children, when they were young, to actually do what they were trained for (not told to do - *trained for*) when lost for instance) and it miserably failed in most of the cases :)

Answer (score 27):

> "I'm sorry but I'd rather not trade seats."

If they insist;

> "No, I am not going to be changing seats, I'm sorry."

Answer (score 26):

Here's the economist's solution: **Offer a price at which you are willing to give up the seat.**

If he refuses the offer, then too bad for him. If he accepts the offer, then both of you are better off---for the price bargained, he gets the seat and you willingly give up your seat.

Answer (score 25):

If you are very shy and have a lot of difficulty dealing with people directly, a very simple strategy is to lean back in your seat with your eyes closed and wearing headphones or earplugs until after takeoff. Most people will not disturb you while you're like this.

I realize this isn't a direct answer to the question "how do I tell them no", but it might help you avoid people asking you in the first place.

Comment: This definitely isn't a "how do I tell them no", it's an entire survival technique on RyanAir flights!

Answer (score 20):

I totally feel you. I had this happen to me for a seat that I had paid extra just to be seated there. I politely informed them that I had specifically requested this seat and would not change my mind. The person seated did not bother to move and seemed indecisive for a little while and I just waited for him to come to terms with what was happening. Finally the person moved to their respective seat and I could sit in the one that I had paid for.

While I was standing, I was thinking about my options in-case if the person decides to sit there and not move, one of which was to inform the flight crew. Just like you described in the question, I also feel really bad going to a higher authority to get my problems solved, but in certain situations that might be one of the only ways to resolve the situation. I would suggest that you try holding onto the seat and being firm with your answer as you will never be seeing the person who you are removing from your seat. But if nothing works out, call the cabin crew and make up some health BS.

Comment: You definitely needed to inform the flight crew, at the very least to have back up when you claimed back the money for the seat you'd paid extra for. I guess in an extreme view, this was theft of a service!

Comment: Yes, they print you something similar to a boarding pass with details of the payment you made. I definitely had that in case if it ever got to that level. But, these are awkward situations in which no one should put in.

Comment: In this case you should INSTANTLY inform the flight crew.  Don't even talk to or address the person in question.  Tell a crew member.

Answer (score 19):

Another note that hasn't yet been mentioned is redirecting the person.

*"I'm sorry you were not assigned the seat you needed.  I cannot help you, but perhaps one of the attendants can.  Shall I press the call button so they can help you?"*

While the base action is the same as other suggestions - saying no and calling the attendant if pressured - the wording is designed to give them no way to argue with you, and immediately tells them what will happen if they continue to pressure you.

If they pressure you, or ask why you can't help them, simply move forward with the only thing you can help them with:

*"Again, I can't help you, but I'm pressing the call button and someone will be here shortly who may be able to help you. I hope you are able to have this situation resolved."*

Don't give them even an inch.  Don't give them any information they don't need to know - and the *only* thing they need to know is that you cannot help them resolve their problem. Don't suggest you have a medical issue.  Don't suggest you have a preference.  Don't give them any opening which would allow them to argue with you that their "need" might be greater than yours.

Just say no, call the attendant if pressured, and ignore them.

Comment: I like this answer because it rightfully places the responsibility anywhere else besides yourself. I recently gave up my seat willingly to a family looking to sit together, which I do regret because I preferred aisle and reserved it months in advance. Even though switching seats is nice, the ONLY TWO causes for the outcome are that the passenger didn't plan ahead, or the airline put them in the wrong seats. I also like the answer because the only two options are "no" or "talk to authority," which many people will just avoid, leading them to give up on the request if they didn't really need it.

Comment: @alexk: You can't imagine families being forced to organize trips without enough time to "plan ahead" due to external circumstances? Do you think *"Sucks that your father/husband died in a car accident, it's obviously your fault for not reserving a ticket 6 months earlier."*?

Comment: @Mehrdad Of course that happens, but I'm not sure why it's relevant to this question, this answer, or alexk's comment.  If you have to travel for an emergency, you may not be able to sit together as a family.  It makes a difficult situation worse, but there are ways to mitigate that, such as choosing an airline that assigns seats at the gate and arriving early, or purchasing more expensive seats, etc.  No one is blaming the family that can't sit together in these circumstances, they certainly can't plan ahead in an emergency, but that doesn't make it another person's problem to fix either.

Comment: @AdamDavis: I'm responding to *"the ONLY TWO causes for the outcome are that the passenger didn't plan ahead, or the airline put them in the wrong seats"*.

Comment: @Mehrdad Correct.  And you CANNOT plan ahead in an emergency. Even though it's not your fault - you couldn't have planned ahead if you wanted to - it's still your responsibility and inconvenience.  Forcing someone else to give up their seat due to your emergency isn't a right you have, even in your emergency situation.  It's still your responsibility, not someone else's.  All his comment is meant to convey is that while there may be *options* there's no right for such a passenger to force their emergency to inconvenience others.

Comment: @AdamDavis: I never claimed it's someone else's responsibility or inconvenience.

Comment: @Mehrdad I guess I fail to see the point of your comment then. alexk said *"the ONLY TWO causes for the outcome are that the passenger didn't plan ahead, or the airline put them in the wrong seats."* which is the point you seem to take issue with, but then you present a situation where the passenger didn't plan ahead.  The only difference you *might* be able to point out is that "didn't" --> "couldn't" but didn't still covers that case.

Comment: @Mehrdad Let's all calm down here. I was probably too harsh in my original comment, for sure - I was trying to speak in the context of an answer for someone who does not want to say yes to the request unless directly ordered to do so by the flight crew. I also realize in retrospect that there are more than two reasons for flyers to not have the seats with their family or seats they prefer - reasons that definitely include family emergency. In an era where seat selections now routinely cost extra money, I don't blame anyone for wanting to very firmly decline this kind of request when possible.

Comment: I also think that anyone should realize that switching seats may be against the contract of carriage, airline rules, or country-specific regulations. Perhaps a flight crew member needs to at the least be made aware of any seat change whether or not the seat switch is wholeheartedly arranged between passengers.

Answer (score 17):

I think what you describe happens quite often in parts of the world where the pecking order is based on age, so teenagers rank slightly better than animals, but only slightly. Older people try to take undue advantage of their position in the pecking order.

I have been in the same situation as you. I found that the best solution in such a situation is to say that you have an injury or problem, say problem with your back or your foot and so you won't be able to travel in the alternative seat being offered. This worked most of the time. Sometimes the person trying to take advantage of you might be somewhat obnoxious and they may persist. They may do one of the following:

1. Ask for further details of your injury or problem.
2. Claim they have a bigger problem than you have and you are young anyway.
3. Mutter something about inconsiderate teenagers or perhaps something rude, or glare at you in a nasty way.

For case 1, say "I have a very good doctor to treat me so please don't worry about it".

For case 2, ask them to switch seats with someone else who is healthy, as you are in the same condition as Mr. Obnoxious.

For case 3, ignore them. They did not succeed in taking advantage of you. They lost. You won. Do not be intimidated by them.

Try not to give off vibes of diffidence and shyness. Obnoxious people seem to sense that like a crocodile senses an injured prey in the water. Observe your body language and change it as needed.

Answer (score 11):

Since I prefer window seats, this does not happen to me often but the few times it has happened, it is because it is a parent (usually father) who wishes to sit with their family in the other 2 seats.

As a parent myself, I can understand the desire to want to sit with your family, especially when the family consists of multiple young children.  A grumpy young child can make the flight uncomfortable for **everyone** and if the parent thinks they can help keep the child calm, it might actually make the flight more pleasant for all.

However, if you need to sit in the seat you reserved in advance, then it is your seat.  I should have no right to force you to move, and I personally, would not be upset by someone refusing to change seats because I asked.  However, if the issue is only the need for the aisle and not a specific seat you might want to check if the passenger has an aisle seat.

A simple response might be

> I had a condition that requires me to sit in an aisle.  If you have an aisle seat in a different row, I would happily switch with you.

Then let the person respond.  If they have an aisle, then switch and you don't lose anything.  If they don't, then (hopefully) they will move on.  As a last resort, the flight crew is your friend here.  If the person is bothering you, they will support you.

Comment: There are many times when switching would put you at a disadvantage though. Consider if you already stowed your luggage and there is no empty luggage area near the new seat.

Comment: @Chan-HoSuh then don't move.  it is your seat and up to you.  If there is something you need from the overhead bins, you can take it with you.  Personally, I never put anything in the overhead bin  that I might need during the flight.  I always keep the items I need in my 2nd bag under the seat.

Comment: My point is "you don't lose anything" is not correct. Good luck getting your luggage later if you moved from the back towards the front (without having been able to move it).

Answer (score 9):

It happened to me recently. I had checked in online and reserved the seats I wanted. A guy came to me and asked to change seats so he could sit next to his wife. I told him that my 3 kids were just across the aisle and that I wanted to be next to them. He then tried to convince me that the other seat had more leg room! I just said that I didn't want to change. He went off but the wife fumed the whole way. Her problem - not mine.

You reserve your seat, you get to sit in it - no matter what. The cabin crew want a fast turn-around so they back you up if you have the boarding card.

Answer (score 7):

I would look at this way:

1. To begin with, the other person does not know or understand your need to sit in the aisle. If you tell them that you have special needs for that, or that you payed extra for it, they should be able to understand this.
2. If you tell them that you *need to* or *payed extra for* sitting in the aisle, then that person would be selfish to try to deny you this. As such there is no reason to be shy about answering no, you have every right to do so.

Answer (score 5):

Since your problem is that you lose your seat because of shyness, you'll have to overcome that problem. Not the being shy, but the losing your seat.

The next time it happens, rule number 1: This is YOUR seat. YOU keep YOUR seat. That's the unavoidable outcome. You may become totally embarrassed because you have to say no to people or worse, which is unfortunate, but the whole situation will end up with YOU sitting in YOUR seat.

So when you are asked to change seats, since the outcome is unavoidable it can't be helped that you are less diplomatic and polite than you wish. So the answer to any request is: "This is MY seat and you are not getting it.". That's what you say. It my come as a bit of a shock to you and the person asking you, but its the truth. Fortunate for you, less fortunate for the others. It will come as a surprise to the person asking, so most likely they won't have any comeback.

If they continue arguing, your answer this time is "This is MY seat and you are not getting it.". Oh, that's the same answer. Well, it had to be, because of rule number 1: This is YOUR seat, and YOU keep it.

If you need to answer again, you may add: "This is MY seat and you are not getting it. We both know that. If you don't leave my alone I'll have to call a flight attended. "

A flight attendant will be only too happy to help you. Taking care of an unruly passenger is something that puts a bit of excitement into their life.

And I'll just repeat the number 1 rule: It's YOUR seat and YOU keep it.

Answer (score 5):

You have a seat that presumably you paid for. You are not under any obligation to switch seats with another passenger, and you do not owe them any explanation. If someone asks, simply say, "No, sorry". Then turn away and direct your attention to something else, open a book or start using an electronic gadget or something, to indicate that the conversation is over. Do not continue looking at them and wait for an acknowledgement from them, because that just invites them to press the matter.

If you say no and the person pushes, I'd give the briefest of explanation. If there's some specific reason why you prefer this seat, say so. "No, sorry, but I like a seat near the middle of the plane" or whatever. Or just, "No, I like this seat." Don't yell and don't get into an argument. If the person continues to be insistent, say, "If you need help finding your seat, I'd be happy to call the flight attendant for you" and indicate the call button. If he still pushes, really do call the flight attendant.

Unless the other person has some good reason for wanting to change seats -- if he has a medical problem and for some reason your seat would be better or something -- I doubt the stewardess will tell you that you must give up your seat.

As someone else noted, I'm surprised that you say this issue comes up a lot. Maybe it's different in India, but here in the U.S., I think once in my life I've had someone ask me to change seats, and that was because a family had been split up.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but with regards to the last paragraph: the last time I flew transatlantic I was asked to swap seats on both the flight out and the flight back. In both cases it was so that a couple could sit together, and on the flight back I got a slightly nicer seat that the one I was supposed to be in.

Comment: Maybe it's worth adding: If someone does have a good reason to ask you to switch seats with them -- like so that a family can sit together -- then unless you have a good reason to refuse, I'd think it would be reasonable courtesy to agree. If someone's just saying, "Hey I made my reservation late and got stuck with a middle seat but I prefer an aisle seat, so you should give me yours", I'd say no. But "The only seats we could get put my six-year-old is in the front of the cabin while I'm way in the back", I'd be inclined to switch.

Answer (score 4):

I'll provide my take on this:

**As much as I agree you can every right to keep your seat, remember that other travelers can be stressed out as well. Stressed people can do crazy stuff that is not in their regular nature.** They might want to sit with their families or children and do not realize why you traveling alone cannot be bothered to change. (In all honesty, I've flown a bit and never considered this. I thought claustrophobic people preferred window seats). Their concern for their kid may be as bad as your claustrophobia. Saying no in this case, while you have your right to, might make the situation worse.

- They may escalate it to flight attendant and get more people involved, "causing a scene". This also would suggest they are not prepared to give in easily. If it can be solved at earlier stage ("Do you have another aisle seat for me?") it may work better. No toilet rows? For smaller aircraft (A320/B737) try "I have a short connection and would really like an aisle seat at the front of the plane".
- They might come over to your seat for the rest of the flight with a legitimate cause if they have kids that need to be attended to for instance. I might am not familiar with claustrophobia, but I don't think this sort of stuff would help if you are shy. If they are unfriendly with a legitimate cause, I don't think it will improve. My parents declined a seat change some time ago, only to have that person annoyed and bother them the rest of the flight.
- Test around what works best. For instance, use the gate agents to your advantage and ask how full the flight is. If it's not entirely full, try to board a little later. You will still have legitimate access to your allocated aisle seat, but you can also easily see if there are other free seats where you might even get two seats for yourself. Clear possibilities are easier to see than when passengers are crowded up in the aisle. Also opens the possibilities to go communicate via the flight attendant looking that everybody gets settled rather than the passenger occupying, who is normally calmer and more understanding of your cause.

If I would have somebody come up to me at a window or aisle seat and asked for a change and would softly hint at that they were uncomfortable, I would happily oblige to switch if it saves them from feeling shit the rest of the flight. As much as I realize and understand your cause (and your preferred response), perhaps consider picking your fight wisely.

Answer (score 3):

I usually say "I will swap seats if requested by the cabin crew. Here, let me call one for you." And this is the truth, even when I move myself to another seat I always ask the crew whether it's OK.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand why so much animosity against people asking to change in some answers and comments.

I agree that asking to change for a better seat and sending the OP near the toilet is bad but that's not the most common situation.

I once asked someone to switch with me, to be near my family. No, this was not a trick and I didn't book my travel late. Nor I thought that doing it loud would get me some advantage.

Sometimes places are just assigned and/or you can't pick them. It will be hard to keep a group together.

I was careful enough to ask a person that was sitting in the same position as I was, near me, and apparently without family.

If the person answered that she didn't want to or couldn't change I would just accept it. I would love going with family, but its the person's place. I think most people respect that.

All this to conclude: Don't be afraid to just politely refuse as others already answered. You can also give an explanation. That usually helps others understand. Not that you have to do it, but it will give you a feeling of assurance and the other will also accept it better.

Comment: "Sometimes places are just assigned and/or you can't pick them. It will be hard to keep a group together."  So why can't people just accept it and not bother others?

Comment: @Andy If you've got some number of children (and that could include only 1 or more), having more than one adult nearby to deal with them will likely make the flight better for everyone on board. Perhaps the family got bumped or re-routed that wasn't their fault.

Comment: @Andy I understand the question and I agree with the OP. It can be annoying if happening all the time. But I don't think that's so general. If you're switching one or two seats I don't see a problem with moving. You can make someone else life more pleasant while yours will be the same. You just need to stand up, walk 2 steps and sit.

Comment: @nsn You're assuming people don't have seat preferences and they don't care where they sit.  Moving from an asile seat to a window seat might make their life less pleasant.  Frankly if its such a big deal then reserve your seats ahead of time.  The family that gets bumped might not have that option, but they should really make it the airlines problem to see if there are any volunteers to move around to accommodate the bumped family, much like they ask for volunteers to be bumped to begin with.

Comment: @Andy not at all. I end my answer saying that I respect the persons choice. I just don't understand why such fuss about something so simple. A person wants to move to a new place. Fine itś in her right to ask. The sited person does not want to change. Fine its her place. It just seems that now asking is the worst thing possible.

Comment: I only responded to your comment, not remembering you were also the answerer.  And I never said it was the worst possible thing; however maybe some people just don't want to be bothered, and if its trivial as you suggest, then why ask to begin with?  My experience though is that people that ask feel entitled to have you comply and at best get pissy with you when you don't, and at worse continue to badger you.

Answer (score 3):

I am normally happy to change seats as long as the seat is of equivalent comfort.  It is just not that big of deal for me.  I have changed when the seat was not as good just because I felt like being generous that day.

However, I was recently asked to change seats from an aisle to a center seat.  A man wanted me to change so he could sit with his wife.  I wanted to use my laptop and the extra space on the aisle was important to me.  I simply smiled and very politely declined.  Everyone around me knew I declined. Later he asked the lady sitting in the window to change with his wife.  She accepted.  Many of the other passengers heaped praise on her for changing seats; **This was obvious a back handed way of shaming me for not changing seats.  I dealt with it by joining in on the over the top praise.**

Another time I was asked to change seats for a lesser seat on international flight.  The gentleman knew it was not as good of a seat.  He handed me his card and said I should contact him if I needed any assistance while visiting his country.  He worked in the office of the President.  I never needed to call him, but if I had, it would have been well worth changing seats.

Overall it is a no-brainer to switch if the destination seat is better.

Answer (score 1):

From a moral point of view, their request is identical to a stranger asking you for $20. They have the right to ask, but you have absolutely no moral or legal obligation to give. In some situations it will be nice to help them out, in others it will be stupid. But in no situation is it required of you to help them.

The only things you **cannot/should not** do:

- Curse at the person(e.g. say "F**k off")
- Get physical (push the person, hit the person).

If the other person does any of these 2 things the single thing **you must do** is shout "help" repeatedly until either someone intervenes or they move away.

To decline their request, absolutely everything except the above is perfectly acceptable. But I strongly advise against giving a reason, because that can lead to them trying to argue, which would probably be uncomfortable for you. Saying "No." is sufficient. So is shaking your head. So is ignoring them. Or holding out your hand with your palm facing them. At worst people will think that's weird. Remember, their request is the same as asking you for $20.

On a related note I also suggest you practice in front of a mirror two everyday responses:

- A friendly "No thank you."
- An assertive "No."

Answer (score -1):

Just can give an explanation in addition to making clear that you are not going to give up your seat so as to make your refusal sound a lot more polite. E.g.  I usually say that I need to visit the toilet quite frequently when I make clear that I'm not going to give up my aisle seat. In your specific case you could say that you need to get up to stretch your legs quite frequently which is going to bother other passengers a lot (e.g. after food is served) unless you have the aisle seat.

Just compare the following two sentences:

"No, I'm not going to give up my seat".

"Sorry, I have chosen this aisle seat as I have to get out of my seat quite frequently and I also don't want to sit in the back of the plane".

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I don't think lying is the best way to enforce a right I should have anyway.

Comment: @VedantChandra not to mention that needing to use the toilet frequently is hardly a likely reason for someone to want to *avoid* a seat that is close to the toilet.

Comment: Yes, but I was addressing the general question, not the particular incident, of how you could argue that you aisle seat is the best choice. Thing is that your right doesn't need to be enforced, the problem seems to be that you are just too shy a person to just ignore suggestions by other passengers. Now, you can't change your character overnight, so you should have some options available. Lying isn't a bad thing, we do it all the time (see also Berit's answer). In fact, your problem is actually that you are lying to yourself every time you give in to suggestions of other passengers.

Comment: @CountIblis someone else pointed out that giving a reason for your refusal provides the other party with grounds to argue against you.  That is also true if the reason is false.  In most situations, at least, a strategy of "I do not want to give up my seat, period" may be more likely to succeed with less effort.

Comment: I think you are all missing the point that this explanation comes on top of his enforceable right to stick to his assigned seat. If someone asks if you'd like to change seats, you say no (which by itself should be enough), but that sounds rather impolite but you can deal with that by giving an additional explanation that is more about why you chose that seat at the time of online check in, in the first place. So, you could say: "sorry but I deliberately chose this aisle seat because ...." and "...." can be anything, e.g. "I need to get up and stretch my legs regularly".